# Using a date field from a form in an access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I currently have a query that uses a date field from a form. Everything compiles fine, the problem is when I try an expand on this. I want to specify a date one day ahead of the date displayed on the form. My current SQL used to grab the date is

```
WHERE ((DateValue([TIMESTAMP]))=[Forms]![Frm_Start]![Date])
```

However when I try to add + 1 to the end it displays this message:

> The expression is typed incorrectly, or is too complex to be evaluated.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `PARAMETERS` clause as the first line of your SQL to inform the db engine the form control contains a Date/Time value.

```
PARAMETERS Forms!Frm_Start![Date] DateTime;
```

Then use the parameter with `DateAdd()` in your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE DateValue([TIMESTAMP])=DateAdd("d", 1, Forms!Frm_Start![Date])
```

However, that will require running `DateValue()` for every row in the table.  This should be faster with `[TIMESTAMP]` indexed:

```
WHERE
        [TIMESTAMP] >= DateAdd("d", 1, Forms!Frm_Start![Date])
    AND [TIMESTAMP] < DateAdd("d", 2, Forms!Frm_Start![Date])
```

Comment: Both TIMESTAMP and Date are reserved words.  Suggest you rename them if possible.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is:

```
SELECT Table1.[ADateTime]
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.[ADateTime] Like ([forms]![Table1]![ADate]+1) & "*"
```

Dates are numbers with the decimal as a time, so another possibility:

```
SELECT Table1.ADateTime
FROM Table1
WHERE CLng([ADateTime])=[forms]![Table1]![ADate]+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the dateadd function:

```
`dateadd("d",1,mydatefield)`
```